# how to use grid layout in android for fixed row and column which should be stretchable

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am working on one android project in which i want layout which include 3*2 grid type structure where each cell contain textview and imageview.

And this imageview and textview should fill entire screen of mobile regardless of its screen resolution. In other words, it should be stretchable. 
I am confused whether to use grid layout or table layout in this case.
So please give me best way to do this thing.

Comment: you can specify this android:numColumns="3" attribute in your xml for gridview. If you want rows and columns use table layout

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use grid view with base adapter.

Comment: GridView does not allow to stretch rows,only columns. it's sad.