# Trying to get Android LinearLayout to stretch horizontally and vertically

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout, stretch

UPDATE:  I appreciate the advice to use GridView, and I do believe that would provide better performance.  However, my initial efforts at implementing a simple GridView have resulted in shameful failure.  I suppose figuring out what I  am doing wrong is for another topic.  To fix this implementation, I used OnWindowFocusChanged to find ANDROID_CONTENT height, then divided by the number of rows to set row height.  The major lesson here that is not present in many of the discussions on this issue is OnCreate is the WRONG place to set dimensions.  OnWindowFocusChanged occurs later when accurate measurements can be made.  This information is not mentioned often in the many, many discussions on this topic.

ORIGINAL:
I am working on an Android layout trying to set up a board with three columns and four rows.

I want to stretch the board to fill the available screen both vertically and horizontally.  I tried nesting LinearLayout by row and column with the `weight="1"` option, but could only get it to stretch horizontally.

In the following configuration, the rows stretch to fill the width of the screen, but the columns are set at **"60dp"**.  I have tried GridLayout and TableLayout also, but haven't been able to get the desired result.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft = "10dp"
        android:paddingRight = "10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/player1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/player2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />    
        <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/row0"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:layout_below="@id/player2"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
          android:baselineAligned="false"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position0"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" /> 
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
        </LinearLayout>  
        <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/row1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_below="@id/row0"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:baselineAligned="false"
          android:orientation="horizontal">    
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" /> 
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position4"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
        </LinearLayout>      
        <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/row2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_below="@id/row1"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
          android:baselineAligned="false"
          android:orientation="horizontal"> 
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position6"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position7"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position8"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
        </LinearLayout>      
        <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/row3"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_below="@id/row2"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
          android:baselineAligned="false"
          android:orientation="horizontal">   
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position9"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />    
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position10"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/position11"
           android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/positionHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/square" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I disagree with others saying you *must* use a GridLayout. Try this approach with a LinearLayout. I used a generic View for each cell of the grid, but any control will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

This approach also requires no manual manipulation of the layout in code, everything is handled in the xml using weights.

Comment: you may see the lint warning "nested weights are bad for performance", and that might be true, but test it for yourself, i don't think you'll notice any performance issues with a layout this simple.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do in the first place.  I'll give this a try.  I agree my solution is "hacky" but it works well!  In the interest of learning, I need to try your solution.  And yes, that lint warning did scare me off at first, but I'll try it anyway.

Comment: i personally use nested weights all the time and have yet to see any negative impact, even when having 50+ views on one layout.

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_clm1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/yellow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_clm1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/red" />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- second Row -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_clm1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_clm2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/yellow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_clm3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/red" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Am I missing some of the xml?  Seems like the top is not there.

Comment: I think I see what you are doing here.  I get a warning when I nest weights like this.  In your opinion, is that not something to worry about when there's only 2 levels?

Comment: @smirciat that's trick.but you have to always used Griedview for this type of view.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not a good idea to use so many Layouts. You should use `TableLayout` or `GridLayout` instead.

**GridLayout:**

- [Related StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560547/how-to-use-grid-layout-in-android-for-fixed-row-and-column-which-should-be-stret)
- [Official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)
- [Very good tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)

**TableLayout:**

- [Official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)

Comment: I have attempted a few TableLayout and GridLayout examples, but have been unable to get either to fill the entire available area horizontally and vertically.

Comment: I think you should then post your question relating GridLayout, not so many LinearLayouts. What was the problem?

Comment: Check out my updated answer with third tutorial, which is a good example on how to use GridView. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my UPDATE above, the real trick here is setting dimensions somewhere other than OnCreate.  I initialized player1, player2, and position[] as the LinearLayout elements from the xml, then in onWindowFocusChanged I adjusted their height to fit.  Not as good as GridView as suggested by others here, but its something I can actually make work!

with help from:
http://www.rapidsnail.com/developer/topic/2011/222/27/35613/title-bar-and-get-out-of-the-view-of-the-status-bar-display-area-height.aspx

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            View content = getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT);
            player1.getLayoutParams().height=content.getHeight()/6;
            player2.getLayoutParams().height=content.getHeight()/6;
            for (int i=0;i<12;i++){
                    position[i].getLayoutParams().height=content.getHeight()/6;
            }
```

Comment: while this may work, it's pretty hacky in my opinion, take a look at my answer which will get you the desired result just using weights appropriately in the xml layout

Comment: As I commented on your answer, I agree with you.  One point I really want to stress to anyone searching for answers on this issue is many new Adroiders like me try to set screen dimensions from onCreate in the Activity.  The fact that this is a bad idea but will work later is not mentioned often enough in help forums.