# layout_weight for both horizontal and vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a situation like this:

[image: Sample app]

I have layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" >

        <!-- using relativelayout I can match background size to content -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/riderTable"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/riderTable"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/riderTable"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/riderTable"
            android:background="@drawable/rider_opisowe" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/riderTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <!-- TextViews here -->
            </TableRow>
            <!-- more rows -->

        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPhoto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And 60%/40% ratio is working, however imageview (white square) is not matching blue box height. I want the image container to have width of 40% of parent's, the same height as blue box and contain image.

Already tried this: [Trying to get Android LinearLayout to stretch horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561404/trying-to-get-android-linearlayout-to-stretch-horizontally-and-vertically)
However simple example described there is just using one-color backgrounds, if I switch to images this is not working as expected. So putting it inside another linearLayout does not solve the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `android:layout_height` from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` for your `ImageView`.

```
      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPhoto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/myImage" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think I was so close to correct solution! Few hours of trying and it's just this!

Comment: sometimes it happends.

Answer (score 2):

Your layout should look more like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="6" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And you could replace left and right frame layouts with whatever you wish.

Comment: Please Add image if possible.

Answer (score -1):

try this it may help

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPhoto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage" />
```